# Specifying a different config file for fish shell

Tags: config, fish

Is is possible to run fish with a different config file overriding the default one that is stored in the file `.config/fish/config.fish` (or even with no config file)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Fish looks for its configuration in $XDG_CONFIG_HOME/fish, or ~/.config/fish if that is unset. So set XDG_CONFIG_HOME to e.g. /tmp (or even /dev/null) before starting fish.

Comment: That's what I do when I'm testing newer versions to avoid messing up my existing configuration.

Answer (score -1):

This feature is not currently available in fish, but you could use `eval` in order to evaluate things in the current shell, avoiding to load the `config.fish` file.

Comment: Can you provide an example?

Comment: I needed to execute something in the fish shell (like `curl http://... | fish`) but I needed it not to source the `config.fish` file (since the line was already in the `config.fish` file and I had to avoid loops). So i turned it to `eval (curl http://...)`